# using regex to match patterns from one column and creating a new column based on the column attribute names

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a `Pandas DataFrame` of the form:

**Current**

```
product_typ

[Milo, Milk, Sugar]
[Water, Tea, Milo]
[Bread, Water]
[Bread, Water, Milo]
[Salt, Water, Milo]
[Milo, Milk, Water, Bread]
[Salt, Milk, Bread]
[Milo, Milk]
```

I would like to create a new column with regex of the form. Keep in mind that it is a `Pandas DataFrame`

**Expected Output**

```
product_typ                          matched_col

[Milo, Milk, Sugar]                Product_Milo_Milk_Sugar
[Water, Tea, Milo]                 Product_Water_Tea_Milo
[Bread, Water]                     Product_Bread_Water
[Bread, Water, Milo]               Product_Bread_Water_Milo
[Salt, Water, Milo]                Product_Salt_Water_Milo
[Milo, Milk, Water, Bread]         Product_Milo_Milk_Water_Bread
[Salt, Milk, Bread]                Product_Salt_Milk_Bread
[Milo, Milk]                       Product_Milo_Milk
```

I tried to attempt this with `str.findall` `matching` the `pattern` works but the replacement got me quite thinking.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```
df['matched_col'] = ['_'.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['product_typ']]
```

#### OR

```
In [1687]: df['matched_col'] = df['product_typ'].apply('_'.join)
```

Example:

```
In [1681]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['a','b','c'], ['b','c']]})                                                                                                                                             

In [1682]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1682]: 
           A
0  [a, b, c]
1     [b, c]

In [1684]: df['b'] = ['_'.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['A']]                                                                                                                                               

In [1685]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1685]: 
           A      b
0  [a, b, c]  a_b_c
1     [b, c]    b_c
```

Comment: I get an error ```TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found``` and when I check the first item, this is it --> ```['Milk', 'Milo']```

Comment: Please apply this only on the column which has lists not on the entire dataframes. Another reason could be that this column contains float values. Try to apply this on a sample of dataframe which you are sure that it contains proper list of string values.